# Reinstalled Windows 7 on new HDD, installed Linux over previous Windows 7 on old HDD, how to dual boot?

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, multi-boot, bootsector

I reinstalled Windows 7 on my new HDD, installed Linux over the previous Windows 7 on the old HDD. How do I dual boot?

It seems that I overrided the Windows bootsector in the original HDD that was able to redirect to new HDD where new Windows is.

Do I need to create some kind of Windows bootsector to the new HDD that has an NTFS filesystem, or can I direct the GRUB2 bootloader directly to the HDD that has Windows installed? If so, how do I do it?

*Update:* This is not a question of how to use GRUB2. It seems that something might be missing in the Windows 7 HDD. I used the Windows installation DVD and its command prompt to set the MBR to the NTFS HDD `bootsect /nt60 all` and went from BIOS directly to that HDD. It complained that the disk had no bootloader. I think that even if I set a GRUB chain, it would not work.

Comment: Google "grub bootloader"

Comment: Please log in as the user you posted this question with and don't make anonymous edits -- you're gonna have a hard time commenting and clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

GRUB supports a style of booting called **chainloading**, where it punts off to another existing bootloader. This style is made necessary here because GRUB has no idea how to boot Windows, which as far as I know, is not multiboot compliant.

If you are using GRUB Legacy:

1. Open up the file `/boot/grub/menu.lst`
2. Add the following text:

   ```
   title Windows 7
   root (hdx,y)
   makeactive
   chainloader +1
   ```

---

For GRUB 2:

1. Open up the file `/etc/default/grub`
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   menuentry "Windows 7" {
   set root=(hdx,y)
   chainloader +1
   }
   ```

---

Either way, replace the `x` with your hard drive number and your the `y` with Windows 7's partition number. To find that out, open up a partition editor like GParted.

For reference, both the hard drive number **and** the partition number start from 0. So, for example:

- First Hard Drive, Second Partition => (hd0, 1)
- Second Hard Drive, First Partition => (hd1, 0)
- Ninth Hard Drive, Twenty Second Partition => (hd8, 21)
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the bios boot select menu to select the drive you want to boot. This can usually be accessed by selecting a key like F2/F10/F12/ESC at boot time. The benefit to doing it this way is that each OS has it's own Bootloader.